# CentOS 7.8: yum update changes "taskbar" behavior with super key; how to configure?

Tags: centos, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I did a fresh VM install of CentOS 7.8.  When I did a

```
sudo yum -y update
```

(900 packages!), the behavior changed when I hit <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

I am not certain I am using the right terminology.  When I use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, I no longer have a launcher / open apps / shortcut bar on the left side of the screen. I also have noticed a new button in bottom left and a change to the multi-desktop selector bottom right.

I assume there was an update within the last 3 weeks or so (since the last time I installed a VM).  I assume this is a GNOME desktop change.

I simply don't know where to look to change options or what to search in Google.  I don't know I am using the correct terminology here, either, which is critical to doing a google search.

I would like to get the bar with open programs & frequent shortcuts back.

Old appearance with <kbd>Super</kbd> key:
[image: Super key: Old behavior w/ Bar]

New appearance with <kbd>Super</kbd> key:
[image: Super key: New behavior]

Comment: Try this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681111/504900

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, and it's a "GNOME" vs "GNOME Classic" difference that changed with the most recent update to CentOS 7. If you log out and click on the gear before you log back in, you can select "GNOME" instead of "GNOME Classic". I observed this issue when updating a fresh install of CentOS 7.5 today.

Comment: Excellent!  I did not have a gear on the splash screen, but google put me onto this bash command to fix it :  gnome-shell --mode=user -r &     EDIT: typo

Comment: Yes! this command works on CentOS 7.9 version too

Answer (score 0):

You can install GNOME Tweak Tools via 
`sudo yum install gnome-tweak-tool -y` 
if not installed by default and then update your appearance as you see fit. 
You can also check for extensions in the Software Manager that allow you to extend your settings for the GNOME window manager.

Comment: I am confident that this is not a gnome-tweaks issue or change in gnome-tweaks extensions.  I have two VMs, one with the update, and one without.  The settings are the same and no extensions are active.  On my "missing bar" instance, when I turn the extensions off (just to double-check), the screen behavior does not change.