# vncserver with Centos 7: How to change the Gnome environment?

Tags: centos, gnome, vnc

I use Centos 7 with gnome.
Gnome classic doesn't support the superkey search anymore and I'd like to move to `gnome`.

- `~/.vnc/xstartup` already uses `gnome` instead of `gnome-classic`:

```
if [ -e `/usr/bin/gnome-session --session=gnome`  -o -e /usr/bin/startkde ]; then
    vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
fi
```

Nevertheless, the environment I see in the VNC client window is `gnome-classic`.

The environment used by default with a real monitor is `gnome` not `gnome-classic`.

- **How can I change the environment?**

Comment: What do you have in ~/.vnc/xstartup now?  Both GNOME and GNOME classic are just different invocations of gnome-shell.

Comment: I have what is in my question. `gnome-session`, no `gnome-shell`.

Answer (score 1):

DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far...

To re-enable the search box when you press the Super Key (e.g., <kbd>Win</kbd>) in GNOME on CentOS and RHEL 7, open a Terminal and enter the following command:

```
sudo sed -i "s/\"hasOverview\": false/\"hasOverview\": true/g" /usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/classic.json
```

Tested in CentOS 7.9 and RHEL 7.9 using GNOME Shell 3.28.3.

Comment: Duplicate answer posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681115/97255)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop`

You will see:

```
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=classic gnome-session --session gnome-classic
```

Try that in your startup file.   You can probably just do an `export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=classic` before the if block, and change the gnome-session line to uses gnome-classic.

Comment: I want to see `gnome` not the classic that is already displayed even tho xstartup is configured for gnome. Moreover the gnome-session is already present in xstartup (check the piece of code in my question)